# Using Vagrant to launch Windows on AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have been learning how to use Vagrant and can successfully launch linux instances in AWS using Vagrant, but I cannot launch Windows and cannot find any resources online that help in this particular situation. I'm really looking for some more documentation and/or a better explanation of the differences since there is not very much official documentation.